# How do I ask Tire to return only if score more than 1 for elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, full-text-search, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to return only documents that have `_score` more than 1. I'm not sure how to do that. I could get all the returned documents and check again individually in ruby code, but I guess it could be done from elasticsearch directly.

This is the query I have right now.

```
tag_results = Tire.search $index_elasticsearch do
            query do
                boolean do
                    should { fuzzy(:tags, query, {:min_similarity => 0.85}) }
                    should { string "description:#{query}" }
                    should { string "description1:#{query}" }
                end
            end
        end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [min_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/min-score.html) parameter in search to specify a minimum score that must be satisfied for a result to be accepted.

In practice though, scores vary.  You won't get consistent results.  Much better is to make the requirements of your query sufficiently high so that they don't include the only-slightly-relevant results.

For instance, look at using the `minmum_should_match` parameter in `bool` and `match` queries.  it can be set to eg `"60%"`

Comment: DrTech: But how would I do this in Ruby code while calling Tire?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out there's a way to pass min_score to Tire.

IE. if you just want results with score > 1

```
Tire.search $index_elasticsearch do
   min_score 1
end
```